# using solana-sdk in no-std environment

Tags: solana-sdk

I am writing a client side application using the solana-sdk to create/sign transaction in a no-std environment. Since a lot a dependencies in the solana sdk and/or the dependencies of dependencies and so on use "std" features, I am unable to use the solana-sdk. Is there an easy way to get around this problem? Is there an easy way to use the solana-sdk in a no-std

Answer (score 0):

The `solana-program` crate exists to be used in on-chain, which is close to a no-std environment, and can be adapted for a no-std environment.

Unfortunately, it doesn't contain types for creating and signing transactions, so you'll likely need to do some work to pick apart just what you need.

For example, the transaction types exist at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/sdk/src/transaction, and the signing keypairs exist at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/src/signer/keypair.rs.

After that, for sending transactions, you'll likely need to adapt the RPC client to work in a no-std environment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/rpc-client/src/rpc_client.rs

It might be easiest to use an http sender from scratch though.

All that to say: there's no easy way around your problem unfortunately, sorry!